# ABAddressBook normalized phone number

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, abaddressbook

I need to export contacts phone numbers from the user address book to a remote server.
My server expecting a normalized phone number,
for example if I get contact number: (541) 754-3010
the normalized number should be: 5417543010

my question is about the country code, I want to detect if a number already include a country code and if not to set it myself.

It would be nice if I could query the `ABRecordRef` to know if a country code exists, but I don't think I can.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I am guessing that you want to strip brackets and whitespace so you can store the number as  an integer instead of a string. This is a bad idea as telephone numbers are not restricted to integers and may contain letters and special characters. (Apple itself uses "1800MYAPPLE").

2) You can check whether the value in `kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey` matches the first few characters of your number and, if it doesn't, add them yourself. This is a *little* dangerous and you should just trust the user to supply a correct number.